# For Loop taking too long to execute

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, listbox

I am new to Excel VBA and seek help on this problem:

This section of code, which checks listbox selection, takes too much time to execute when selected item is beyond around 100th in the list. Total items in listbox lb_moviename is around 11,000, hence my concern. Array Ar_Mnm (2 dimensions) holds a) movie name and b) previous selection as 1, if so.

```
    Private Sub lb_moviename_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, 
    ByVal Y As Single)

        c = 0   'counter for change
        For i = 0 To lb_moviename.ListCount - 1
            For j = 0 To UBound(Ar_Mnm, 1)
                If Ar_Mnm(j, 0) = lb_moviename.List(i) Then
                    If lb_moviename.Selected(i) = False Then
                        If Ar_Mnm(j, 1) = 1 Then
                            c = 1       'change occurred
                            MsgBox lb_moviename.List(i) & " deleted"
                            Ar_Mnm(j, 1) = 0
                        End If
                    Else
                        If ArCb_Mnm(j, 1) = 1 Then
                            'c = 0       'no change occurred
                            MsgBox lb_moviename.List(i) & " continues to be selected"
                        Else
                            c = 1       'change occured
                            MsgBox lb_moviename.List(i) & " added"
                            ArCb_Mnm(j, 1) = 1
                        End If
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If c = 1 Then Exit For
        Next i

        End Sub
```

any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Error: Array Ar_Mnm is wrongly mentioned as ArCb_Mnm at some places in my query above. Apologies. The query is still valid.

Comment: If there are wrong thinks in your code, why you do not simple edit the question and correct them? Your code does not only "checks listbox selection"... Your question needs a better description of what the code should do. We can understand what it does, but not to clear what you want accomplishing. So, how `Ar_Mnm` has been filled, declared and how many elements does it contain? Should we understand that only an array your code does use? Please, properly declare all used variables.

Comment: Are the message boxes necessary?